# SQL Update Problem

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update a record in MySQL DB but nothing is being changed.

Here is the line I am using to try to get the record updated.

```
$sql = "UPDATE ".$this->Tbl." SET name = '".$data['name']."', title  = '".$data['title']."', message = '".$data['message']."', ', picture = '".$filename_update.".jpg' WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'";
 echo $sql;
 $db->connect();
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $db->disconnect();
 return $result;
```

There are no errors being reported. In fact I am getting confirmation that all the information is correct in the update line.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query directly in the MySQL client to see that it works there?

Comment: Does the update statement have different values from the record? Does the id exist?

Comment: Can you post the result of "echo $sql;"?

Comment: try using the the output of echo directly in MySQL..see it works there or not..not sure but my guess is the single quotes used along array keys are causing the problem.

Comment: Here is the result of "echo $sql;"

UPDATE obituaries SET name = 'tester', title = 'test', message = 'testr', ', picture = '4d385eca7557a.jpg' WHERE id = '128'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that right before your `picture` column, you have an extra `',`. Perhaps this is causing the issue?

Comment: It indeed was the extra ',
Such a small little thing
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you execute that statement, perhaps try checking for number of records effected.

```
  echo mysql_affected_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say what's happening without seeing the SQL string you construct.

At a guess, however, you have an embedded single quotation mark in message or another variable.